# List with code renders as expected in preview, but inconsistently when posted

Tags: bug

Originally found the problem in [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/207709/33287) and was able to recreate it in the formatting sandbox.

The post contains list mark down, the item contents of which are code blocks. The preview renders the list consistently as expected - both items are shown as:

```
1. block
2. block
```

But when posted, the the second item gets enumerated as `2)` and its vertical alignment is shifted to the right.

Here's my MCVE:

I have tried several different methods that give the same result, not suitable for me.

1)

```
    QMatrix4x4 mat = m_view * m_projection * m_model;
```

2. 

```
    QVector3D screenPos(p.x(),p.y(),1.0f);
```

Preview shows as:

[image: screenshot of preview mode]

And rendered as a post it comes out like this:

[image: screenshot of post with render errors]